# Continue sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Son asked such a task. Continue the number sequence

```
5, 7, 8, 12, 11....
```

The son is in the second grade. They studied the operations of addition, subtraction and multiplication

Comment: I don't see that there is enough here to show a discernible pattern to follow.

Comment: Oeis says ["Distance array associated with ordering A057557 of N X N X N by antidiagonals (distances to xy plane)."](https://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C+7%2C+8%2C+12%2C+11&language=english&go=Search)  I'll bet a lot of money that's not what was intended here.  These numbers look random.

Comment: Continue with $0,0,0,0,0,0 \dotsc$.

Comment: Possibly not a (pure) mathematical but more puzzling task. Is the original text in russian? Try to ask on SE Puzzling.

Comment: @z100 Yes. In russian. Previous sequences were correct. Like `2, 4, 9, 16` or `10, 11, 9, 12, 8`... I trying asked on Puzzling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$5, 7, 8, 12, 11, 17, 14, 22, 17, ...$

I considered skipping each numbers, so

$5, 7, (5+3), (7+5), (5+3+3), (7+5+5), ...$

I think this is correct so

Comment: Perhaps you could share your reasoning.

Comment: Two series? First +3, second +5? Maybe. But to say there is not enough data in the condition. It seems to me that there must be another solution

Comment: But I think this is the simplest way of using addition..

Comment: @AntonShchyrov  can you provide at least one or two terms..?

Comment: @MariosGretsas These are all numbers that are specified as

Comment: ok i see then...in this case i think the solution of @SteveLin is the correct one

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes. But there may be more options

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ...this is possible  because the problem is not well formulated..but the solution of the answerer above maybe a correct one if not the only correct one

Answer (score 0):

For the sequence, $\{a_{n}\}_{n\geq 0}$, given it is fairly easy to see that
\begin{align}
a_{2n} &= 5 + 3*n \\
a_{2n+1} &= 7 + 5*n
\end{align}
for $n\geq 0$ and the potential remaining terms can be obtained from the generating function
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, t^{n} = \frac{5 + 7 \, t - 2 \, t^{2} - 2 \, t^{3}}{(1-t^{2})^{2}}. $$

The first differences generate $\{2, 1, 4, -1, \cdots\}$ and second differences $\{-1, 3, -5, \cdots\}$ which have less of a chance to have a pattern developed without more terms.

Comment: Do you think two elements only are really enough to usethe term "fairly easy to see that"?